# Set Background Color of Dynamically Generated WPF Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a dynamically created `WPF` `Canvas` element inside a `ContentControl` (the same thing happens in a `UserControl`.)  Whenever I attempt to set the background, either upon creation or later on in the program, the background color won't paint (I am however able to set the background on a `Label` inside of the `Canvas` (also added dynamically.)  The creation code I have looks like:

```
_rootGrid = new Grid();
_rootGrid.Name = "_rootGrid";
_rootGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0);
_rootGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
_rootGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
_rootGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
_rootGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
_rootGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
_rootGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(24);
_rootGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);
_rootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star);

_headerBlock = new Canvas();
_headerBlock.Name = "_headerBlock";
_headerBlock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
_headerBlock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
_headerBlock.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += _headerBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
_headerBlock.Background = Brushes.Red;

_title = new Label();
_title.Name = "_title";
_title.Content = "Title";
_title.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
_title.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
_title.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
_title.Background = Brushes.Blue;

_clientBlock = new ScrollViewer();
_clientBlock.Name = "_clientBlock";
_clientBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0);
_clientBlock.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
_clientBlock.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
_clientBlock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
_clientBlock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

_clientArea = new Grid();
_clientArea.Name = "_clientArea";
_clientArea.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
_clientArea.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

_headerBlock.Children.Add(_title);
_rootGrid.Children.Add(_headerBlock);
_clientBlock.Content = _clientArea;
_rootGrid.Children.Add(_clientBlock);
base.Content = _rootGrid;
```

And is called inside of the `ContentControl` constructor.  From that I would expect the header to contain a full row of `Red` with a `Blue` rectangle around the text, but all I get is the `Blue` rectangle around text with most of the row left `Transparent` (noticeable due to the `Green` background of the root `Grid`.)  Any help on this would be appreciated as it is enormously frustrating.  I'm using version `6.2` of the `.NET` framework on `Windows 7` if that plays into it (I have noticed some other odd behaviors, but am going for dynamic generation mostly because these `ContentControl`s take lots of child elements and the `VS 2017` `XAML` parser is too broken to allow them to be named - which makes them virtually useless.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use non-zero Width for ColumnDefinition:

```
_rootGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star); // equal to Width="*" in xaml
```

When `0` is used, Canvas has 0 witdh. But is is possible to see blue Label because Canvas doesn't clip contents on its bounds.

If you try Grid (`var _headerBlock = new Grid();`) with zero width column, there won't be anything displayed at all.

Comment: Thanks,  that's actually the exact solution I hit on after changing it to a Grid myself.